# How to redirect the time a task takes to complete into a log file, given that such task is already redirecting?

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, time, stdout

I have a shell script running a python task, whose stdout is being redirected to a log file:

`python script.py >> log.txt`

I wish to also log the time this task takes to complete, into the same log file. Something like:

`time (python script.py >> log.txt) >> log.txt`

Which, obviously, doesn't work.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `man time` you should be able to use `-o FILE` to output to a file and `-a` to append to the file. So your command should be:

```
/usr/bin/time -a -o log.txt python script.py >> log.txt
```

Using the `-f` flag you can set the desired output format of the times.